# python mysql connector, how to create user defined database

Tags: python, mysql

how do I create a database or table using python mysql connector where the name of the database/table has to be taken as a input from the user. I tried the following but it doesn't works:

mycursor.execute("create database %s", (database_name))

Answer (score 0):

you should make connection without db name.
This should work

```
conn = pymysql.connect('localhost','user','password')
cur = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)    
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE %s;'%('DB_NAME_TO_MAKE'))
```